# Does torrenting to an external hard drive really prevent wear?

Tags: utorrent

Title. I've heard that even if I download torrents an external hard drive, my internal drive will still be prone to wear since the files download onto my internal drive and transfer to the external drive. Is this true? Btw I'm using the utorrent client on a macbook pro 2018.

Answer (score 2):

Most BitTorrent clients write the downloaded files "in-place". They *do not* cache the downloaded chunks in some temporary directory, and there's no technical need to do that anyway – the data can be written straight from memory to the destination.

So if you start a 1GB download and see the client immediately creating a 1GB `.part` file on the external disk, that's where the data goes.

(Of course, if your client has a configurable setting to keep .part files elsewhere, you should make sure that is not enabled...)

---

In rare cases, the client itself (along with the pieces of data it still holds) can be pushed out of RAM into the page file / swap file on your system disk, but that only happens either when the program is completely idle (meaning this won't cause a noticeable amount of disk writes) or when you've completely ran out of RAM (which is rare on its own).